# Reading resource from imported jar in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im using a jar created for a desktop application in Android.

This jar contains some configuration files and read them through

```
(code from .jar)

InputStream fXmlFile = Object.class.getResourceAsStream("/aaa/config/interface_config.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
```

The above code works fine in the desktop application, but when used on Android as imported library gives the following:

```
06-02 05:36:44.748: W/System.err(12001): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
06-02 05:36:44.748: W/System.err(12001):    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:103)
```

which suggests that `Object.class.getResourceAsStream("/aaa/config/interface_config.xml")`
Is returning `null`

I looked inside the generated apk and `/aaa/config/interface_config.xml` exists.

My question is, will `Object.class.getResourceAsStream` work as expected in Android? what i was expecting is `getResourceAsStream("absolutePath")` to return the resource in `"absolutePath"` inside the apk, as it usually does inside a jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the classloader that is used to load `Object` which may not be the same as the one that loaded your class.

If the resource is from the same jar from which the class is loaded that contains this code, change the line to:

```
InputStream fXmlFile = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/aaa/config/interface_config.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i was missing this, it solved it.

Comment: The key here is that getClass() has to be called on an instance of a class that exists in the jar where the desired resource is.